# Residue of $\frac{\sin z}{z^2}$ at zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm self-studying complex analysis by working my way through Gamelin's "Complex Analysis" and I'm stuck on this exercise:

> Find the residue of $\frac{\sin z}{z^2}$ at zero.

Is there a straightforward or simple way to do this? I've tried to look into Gamelin's four rules for calculating residues but I think none of them apply here and the complex integral corresponding to the first negative coefficient of the Laurent series is too tricky for me to solve directly. Should I somehow use the power series representation of $\sin z$?

Sorry for the the minimal effort shown, I find this really challenging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$\frac{\sin z}{z^2}=\frac{z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots}{z^2}=\frac1z-\frac z{3!}+\frac{z^3}{5!}-\cdots,$$then, by definition, the residue is $1$.